# Trying to link a local repo to a remote. Can't see the branches when I run 'branch -a' though

Tags: git

```
git init
(make commits)
git remote add origin someExistingRepo
git fetch origin
git branch -a
```

I would expect this to show my local master as well as all the branches in someExistingRepo, but it only shows my local master. Why? I've gotten it to work by runing *ls-remote*, but I want this local repo to behave like every other repo i've ever worked with. Is there some reason I don't see the other branches? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Is there `remote.origin.fetch` in `git config -l`? If not, run `git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Comment: I only see remote.origin.url. If I run `git remote -v` though I see `origin someExistingRepo (fetch)` and `origin someExistingRepo (push)`

Comment: So you need to config `remote.origin.fetch`, otherwise `git fetch origin`  can't work.

Comment: I tried modifying the config, but now I get an error: `fatal: Invalid refspec someExistingRepo`. I also tried `fetch someExistingRepo` which didn't error, but didn't seem to change anything.